# How can I use variable, loop and shell script to input source and destination bucket path from a text file and execute aws s3 cp command

Tags: bash

I have a file that contains source and destination s3 bucket path information separated by tab spaces.

```
s3://Bucket1/testdata01/childfolder01/164004.png    s3://Bucket2/checksum/1/checksum1.png
s3://Bucket1/testdata01/childfolder01/22636_2.png   s3://Bucket3/checksum/2/checksum2.png
```

How can I use variable, loop and bash shell script to execute below command line by line using the input from the file.

```
aws s3 cp $SOURCE $DESTINATION
```

example:

It will perform something like this based on the lines that the input file has.

```
aws s3 cp s3://Bucket1/testdata01/childfolder01/22636_2.png s3://Bucket3/checksum/2/checksum2.png
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file in a loop and assign the vars

```
while read source dest
do
    aws s3 cp "$source" "$dest"
done < source-dest.txt
```

Comment: Thank you Diego! It worked.
I tried with while loop exact same way except I forgot to add < file.txt ..Lol!